# Textblock's text in button's stackpanel not showing

Tags: wpf, button, text, textblock, stackpanel

I have the following code:

```
 <Button Width="30" Name="RestoreButton" Height="30" Focusable="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="11" Background="Transparent" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" Foreground="Transparent" Margin="0,0,30,0">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="Images/maximizewindow.png" RenderTransformOrigin="1.692,0.564" />
                <TextBlock Text="Teljes méret" Foreground="Gray" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
```

I create a button with an image background. But if I move over, or click on the button, it does not show the textblock's text. Why?

Comment: What is inside in your custom style `ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey`?

Comment: Nothing, it just make my button borderless.

Comment: Is it because you set foreground and background to transparent?

Comment: Please add all relevant XAML, including all the styles you are using

Comment: Is it just when you MouseOver or you are not able to see text not at all?

Comment: I just have copied and paste the code and removed the Style Property and it is working fine Text is Visible but I have chnged the Width and Height to 100 instead of 30